# Unable to convert data '19-10-2002' into date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I need to pass a date parameter in format (dd-MM-yyyy) and convert in this format (yyyy-MM-dd) to send API.

So I do this:

```
convert(date:string){
date //is in the format(dd-MM-yyyy)

date =formatDate(date , "yyyy-MM-dd", 'en_US');
```

and I obtain this error:

```
 Unable to convert "19-10-2002" into a date
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: try using moment js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do

```js
console.log(
"19-10-2002".split('-').reverse().join('-')
)
```

Comment: because your `date` variable isn't in a supported format - it needs to first parse the date in order to format it, and if you are passing a string it requires it to be an  [ISO date-time string](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: @dave—ECMA-262 supports more than just ISO 8601 and in practice built–in parsers support a huge variety of formats (though bugs and inconsistencies between implementations mean that using the built in parser is strongly discouraged).

Comment: @RobG I'm talking about angular's parseDate, not JS in general.  "The date to format, as a Date, or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or an ISO date-time string" https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Comment: @dave—Ok. The answer has no explanation of why the OP has their issue. It would be better to include your comment about supported formats in the answer and replace "it" with "angular.js" since the question is tagged with javascript and typescript too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a string to "formatDate" it has to be in "ISO date-time" format (the complete format is "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD", but you can drop any part from the end and use like "YYYY" or "YYYY-MM-DD"). so the string you are passing to it is not recognized as a valid input date.
so you can use Dave's code

Comment: Well, according to angular documentation, it has to be an iso string: https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the custom date formatter function which accepts date, format and separator/delimiter to convert the passed date with passed format.

```js
function dateFormatter(date, format, delimiter) {
  const dateItems = date.split(delimiter)
  const formatItems = format.toLowerCase().split(delimiter);
  const day = formatItems.indexOf('dd');
  const month = formatItems.indexOf('mm');
  const year = formatItems.indexOf('yyyy');
 
  const formattedDate = ([dateItems[day], dateItems[month], dateItems[year]]).join(delimiter)
  console.log(formattedDate)
  return formattedDate
}

// run example
dateFormatter('02-03-2020', 'YYYY-MM-DD', '-');
dateFormatter('02/03/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY', '/');
```